# Accessing field value array using codeigniter input->post

Tags: codeigniter

I tried everything to get this code below to work with codeigniter.

```
$arrival_date = $_POST['arrival_date'][$re_id]
```

Here's what I do it in codeigniter:

```
$arrival_date = $this->input->post('arrival_date'[$re_id]);
$arrival_date = $this->input->post('arrival_date')[$re_id];
$arrival_date = $this->input->post('arrival_date[$re_id]');
```

All the above three code failed.

Anyone know how to do this in codeigniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$x = $this->input->post('arrival_date');
$arrival_date = $x[$re_id];
```

If your array in the form looks like `name="arrival_date[re_id]"`, then

```
$arrival_date = $x['re_id'];
```

I could help more if you would show the form too.

Comment: this seems to work fine. if I show you the form, is there a better way? I think your code works okay.

Comment: If it works, then there is no reason to show it, try providing more information next time, this was just a lucky guess.

Comment: well, i think the info i have is enough since you have answered it correctly...:). thanks man...